# Autosuggest in JSP using ajax?

Tags: autosuggest

Can anyone tell how to imaplement autosuggest feature to a textbox in jsp using ajax?

Comment: Just Google for an AJAX autosuggest tool (there are plenty out there).  That your initial page is being delivered as a JSP won't make any significant difference -- at the browser end it is still being delivered as an HTML page.  Note that you will need a second URL on the server to deliver the suggestions to the AJAX Javascript in the page.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice [AutoComplete jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) for this. And there's a [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html) showing how easy it is to setup.